# Why doesn't all() stop on the first False element?

Tags: python

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), `all` is equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Then why do I get this output:

```
# expecting: False

$ python -c "print( all( (isinstance('foo', int), int('foo')) ) )"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

When:

```
# expecting: False

$ python -c "print( isinstance('foo', int) )"
False
```

Comment: `int('foo')` is being evaluated before `all` is called.

Comment: Welcome to a strict evaluation mechanism. Maybe you'd prefer to work with Haskell.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what problem you are trying to solve with this code.  I think there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: @dansalmo, some of the conditions I'm checking are function calls. I want to stop evaluation on the first `False` condition.

Comment: @JaceBrowning, below you say  "I only [want] condition2 to be evaluated if condition1 is False. I only want condition3 to be evaluated if condition2 if False, etc."  This is that exact opposite of what you say above.

Comment: @dansalmo, I already corrected that comment on the accepted answer below.

Comment: @Marcin with generators you can achieve what the OP wants in python, too ;-)

Comment: @Ant I'm sorry, but generators will not delay evaluation of a list.

Comment: @Marcin http://stackoverflow.com/a/17367749/429533

Comment: @JaceBrowning You can't create that programmatically, however, unless you use `ast`. It's not really a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments are evaluated before calling a function. In this case first you have to create the tuple you pass to `all`.

`all` never had a chance to check them, the exception was thrown before that.

```
>>> int('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

Comment: Is this the only way to get the pattern I want: `if condition1... elif condition2... elif condition3...`?

Comment: I only condition2 to be evaluated if condition1 is False. I only want condition3 to be evaluated if condition2 if False, etc.

Comment: `cond1 or cond2 or cond3`. But what you posted does something else. *confused*.

Comment: @JaceBrowning, your comment above conflicts with your question.  For lazy detection of False in the manner that you used `all()` it should be `isinstance('foo', int) and int('foo')`

Comment: @dansalmo, My confusion was that I thought `all((f1(), f2(), f3()))` was creating a generator that would be lazily evaluated.

Comment: @JaceBrowning, that is clear, but there are a still a few more confusions to clear up.

Comment: My comment about was inverted. What I meant: I only condition2 to be evaluated if condition1 is **True**. I only want condition3 to be evaluated if condition2 if **True**, etc.

Answer (score 7):

One (fairly ugly) way to get the behaviour you want is via lambdas:

```
all(f() for f in (lambda: isinstance('foo', int), lambda: int('foo')))
```

Comment: +1, When the best solution to a problem is ugly, the problem might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition regarding `all` is correct; you only need to work a little harder to set up a lazy sequence. For example:

```
def lazy():
    yield isinstance("foo", int)   # False
    yield int("foo")               # raises an error, but we won't get here

>>> all(lazy())
False
>>> list(lazy())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in lazy
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

Comment: This is not quite the same as OP's question in that you are applying `isinstance` to all elements yielded by `lazy`.  It just happens to work out with the one example.

Comment: @dansalmo But isn't that the whole point of the excercise, that `all` cuts the evaluation short? I mean, yes, I **would** be applying `isinstance` to all elements returned by `lazy`, except for `all` **stopping** the evaluation before the item that would raise gets a chance to raise. The OP correctly expected short-circuiting to occur, but made a mistake in setting up an eager sequence instead of a lazy one.

Comment: I think your second line should be `yield isintance("foo", int)`. Then you can remove the call to `isinstance` in `all()`.

Comment: @JaceBrowning Good point, I've now edited the answer as per your suggestion. The benefit is that the call to `all()` is now symmetrical to the call to `list()`. The drawback is that this seems to make less sense than a generator expression one would use or encounter in real code.

Answer (score 1):

If the desire to stop evaluation after the first `False` condition is specifically to perform type checking, something like this will work better:

```
if not isinstance(other, MyClass):
    return False
else:
    return all((self.attr1 == other.attr2,
                self.attr2 == other.attr2)) # etc.
```

---

Simplified version from [@catchmeifyoutry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218682/catchmeifyoutry):

```
return isinstance(other, MyClass) and all((self.attr1 == other.attr2,
                                           self.attr2 == other.attr2)) # etc.
```

Comment: please don't post this as an answer, but update your question

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry it's perfectly acceptable for a user to answer their own question, if they discover the solution.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry, I edited the wording to make this sound more like an answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I agree. @JaceBrowning ok then ;) I thought you tried to clarify your question in response to Karoly. By the way, you could reduce your solution to: `return isinstance(other, MyClass) and all( ...)`, which breaks evaluation if the isinstance test fails.

Comment: It is generally acceptable  for a user to answer their own question but the question should be well formed.  This is a case of the same user asking x and answering y.  The original question should have been more directly related to this answer.  See [what-is-the-xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @dansalmo, this is not a case of the XY problem. My unposted code was related to type-checking, but my confusion was specifically about the behavior of `all((f1(), f2(), f3())`, which is why I asked that question.

Comment: You have not stated the problem you are trying to solve with your code. Other than it not working as you expect, what are you trying to do at a higher level?  Are you trying to convert a string to an int only if is convertible to an int?